# Create a custom information window in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible to somehow have way for the Selection.Style (and possibly other info) to always show up in a custom information window similar to the way Debug.Print prints in the immediate windows but ALWAYS visible?

I find myself struggling to quickly check a Selection.Style. MsgBox requires clicking "OK".

I have used the "Reveal Formatting" window but I would like more control over how the information displays.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not using VBA. VSTO can use custom task panes. So can Office JS API. But not VBA

Comment: On further thought... Possibly, a UserForm displayed as non-modal, but using the Windows API to keep it in front. Don't know about dynamically updating it as the seleciton changes, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for knowing the Style at the current selection point, you don't need a custom user form. Place the **StyleGalleryClassic** control on the QAT or a Ribbon tab.

Comment: This works great! It's exactly what I needed. The trick was you have to hover over "style" in the customizing the ribbon dialog to know if you have the correct one. This will save me SO much time.